# Installing "gnatmake" for Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

How do I install `gnatmake` on Cygwin? There is no Cygwin package by that name... Is it a part of any other package? I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNAT), that GNAT is now part of the GCC... So what do I do?

Comment: it seems ADA is not anymore part of the GCC build of cygwin. Last was 8.3 version https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fgcc-ada%2Fgcc-ada-8.3.0-1&grep=gnat.exe

Comment: Sooo. What do I do? Should I try to downgrade gcc?

Comment: I found this: http://gnuada.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php/Install/Cygwin Might be helpful! But I can't find an `.rpm` file that they are talking about there. I could find `.rpm` for multiple OSes, but not for Cygwin!

Comment: I just found out that GNAT became available in GCC in the late 3.x version. It can be obtained with a version of GCC! So I downloaded a version `gcc-3.4.3.tar.bz2` and `gcc-ada-3.4.3.tar.bz2` from official FZF/GNU [website](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-3.4.3/). But, when I extract the `gcc-3.4.3.tar.bz2` and read `gcc-3.4.3/INSTALL/prerequisites.html` I see that in order to build GCC a dependancy is also GNAT, I am citing: *"In order to build the Ada compiler (GNAT) you must already have GNAT installed..."*. WTF??!!! How can I get GNAT if I already need one to compile it in the first place?!